# Standard time for LED light testing

Tags: led, light, testing

What is the exact timing for testing(continuity, electrical parameter, optical parameter, thermal parameter) of LED lamp after manufacturing?

Comment: Depends on your level of quality you aim for and varies from manufacturer to manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

There are various standards depending on whether you are talking about a complete luminaire, a LED module or a retrofit lamp replacement. For example, you might need to look at [IEC 62722-2-1:2014 Luminaire performance - Part 2-1: Particular requirements for LED luminaires](https://webstore.iec.ch/publication/7398) and [IEC 62717 LED modules for general lighting - Performance requirements](https://webstore.iec.ch/publication/64571)

I found this information in this helpful document by [SIRIM QAS International](http://www.sirim-qas.com.my/sirim/core-files/uploads/2016/11/Pocket-Lamp-2016-V2.pdf) and by IEC searches. Another route is to find the standards that are listed in technical information documents of reputable brand manufacturers.